# JMeter: jp@gc Graphs Generator: I got .png just with text "Waiting for sample..."

Tags: jmeter

Graphs are generated, but each .png file contain blank white image with text "Waiting for sample...". What should I do to get the graphs?

Answer (score 1):

I found that the problem was in the first row of csv file generated by listener - the row was empty, so the parser was not able to start calculating the graphs.