# Graphs generated but shows waiting for samples in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

IHi I have the same question as [JMeter: jp@gc Graphs Generator: I got .png just with text "Waiting for sample..."](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24263208/8305811). The jtl file has been created without empty line, have edited the user.properties file.

I followed the steps mentioned in [this link](https://kishorsharma69.wordpress.com/2015/08/12/jmeter-jpgc-graphs-generator/) for the graph generator.

```
 sh jmeter -t /home/Annie/JMeter/grp.jmx -n -l /home/Annie/JMeter/g.jtl     -JTEST_RESULTS_FILE=/home/Annie/JMeter/g.jtl 
Creating summariser <summary>
Created the tree successfully using /home/Annie/JMeter/grp.jmx
Starting the test @ Mon Oct 16 11:27:30 IST 2017 (1508133450438)
Waiting for possible Shutdown/StopTestNow/Heapdump message on port 4445
summary +      1 in 00:00:03 =    0.3/s Avg:  3133 Min:  3133 Max:  3133     Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 2 Started: 2 Finished: 0
summary +     14 in 00:00:14 =    1.0/s Avg:  2731 Min:  2098 Max:  4216     Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 0 Started: 5 Finished: 5
summary =     15 in 00:00:18 =    0.9/s Avg:  2757 Min:  2098 Max:  4216     Err:     0 (0.00%)
Tidying up ...    @ Mon Oct 16 11:27:48 IST 2017 (1508133468522)
... end of run

In log its showing :

WARN o.a.j.v.ViewResultsFullVisualizer:Error loading result renderer:                    org.apache.jmeter.visualizers.RenderInBrowser
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/embed/swing/JFXPanel
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel
```

What should be done to get the graph?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My expectation is that you are using [OpenJDK](http://openjdk.java.net/) on Linux which doesn't have [JavaFX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaFX)

Use your Linux distribution package manager to get [Oracle Java 8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) and make sure JMeter is configured to use Oracle Java instead of OpenJDK.

If you are trying to use [PerfMon Metrics Collector Listener](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/) in GUI mode to test it - make sure **JMeter test is running** at this time as first of all it is a **Listener** therefore it needs to process sample events in order to display anything, it might be even a [Dummy Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/DummySampler/) firing each N seconds. See [How to Monitor Your Server Health & Performance During a JMeter Load Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test) guide for more details.

Comment: "Use your Linux distribution package manager to get Oracle Java 8 and make sure JMeter is configured to use Oracle Java instead of OpenJDK."  I am using Mac and how can I make sure jmeter is configured with openJDK or not